# Monadic parsing functional pearl - gluing multiple parsers together

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am working my way through the functional pearl paper [`Monadic parsing in Haskell`](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jlc/courses/3015/parser_pearl.pdf) (after recommendation at `haskellforall.com` to read that paper to understand parsing). I wrote an implementation until section 4 on page 3 as below:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])

parse (Parser p) = p

instance Monad Parser where
  return a = Parser (\cs -> [(a,cs)])
  p >>= f  = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs' | (a,cs') <- parse p cs])

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser (\cs -> case cs of
                      ""     -> []
                      (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)])

p :: Parser (Char,Char)
p = do { a <- item; item; b <- item; return (a,b)}
```

According to the paper, `p` is a parser that consumes three characters, skips middle one, and returns a pair of first and second. What I can't figure out is how the modified input string is passed to 2nd and 3rd definitions of `item` in `p`. We are not passing the result of first parser to second parser, and so on (because `;`, syntactic sugar for `>>` is used which discards the result as shown by type signature `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`). I will appreciate explanation of how the modified function is being passed in last two invocations of `item` in `p`.

Another thing that confuses me is the handling of `cs` in `item` - it doesn't return (head,tail) pair. Shouldn't it be redefined as follow since the `item` parser consumes one character according to the paper:

```
item :: Parser Char
item = Parser (\cs -> case cs of
                      ""     -> []
                      (c:cs') -> [(c,cs')]) -- redefinition - use cs' to denote tail
```

Comment: ["`do` notation considered harmful"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Do_notation_considered_harmful). :) -- to your 2nd question, the `case` binding shadows the lambda binding. Your code is exactly identical. -- to your 1st, `do` chains define *nested* bind definitions, so there's no need to "pass" anything - the outer binding is just available at the innermost level (as seen in the translation code in the answer below).

Comment: @WillNess, I forgot about that aspect of do notation! I will remember this better now since this time, it stumped me for real :)

Comment: I think that it should be cs' regarding that second part. It does work like that, but my interpretation is that the pattern match shadows the lambda which is quite confusing.

Comment: @radicality, your interpretation seems spot-on. I did a quick check with a function, and verified it. That clears up the confusion about `cs` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try shedding some more light regarding `>>`.
As you see in the other answer, you should desugar the do's into `>>=` to better understand what's going on.

Let's for example write a parser that parses two chars and returns them.

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars = do
  i <- item
  j <- item
  return (i,j)
```

Now, desugar the `do` syntax:

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars =
  item >>= (\i ->
  item >>= (\j ->
  return (i,j) ) )
```

I put brackets for clarity. As you see, the second `item` receives the result of the first `item` parser in the anonymous function, with the result bound to `i`. The `>>=` function takes a parser, a function, and returns a parser. Best way to understand it would be to plug it into the definition:

```
f = \i → item »= \j → return (i,j)
twoChars = item >>= f
twoChars = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs' | (a,cs') <- parse item cs])
```

So we got back a new Parser. Try to imagine what it will do on an input "abc". `cs` is bound to "abc", and the item Parser is used to get back [('a',"bc")]. Now, we apply `f` to 'a', to get back the new parser:

```
item >>= \j -> return ('a',j)
```

This parser will be passed the rest of our string left to process (`"bc"`), and it will use the `item` parser to get out the `b` when the `\j` above is bound to `b`. We then get a `return ('a','b')` statement, which puts `('a','b')` into a parser that just return `('a','b')`.

I hope this clears up how the information flow happens. Now, suppose that you want to ignore a character. You could do it like this.

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars =
  item >>= \i ->
  item >>= \j ->
  item >>= \k ->
  return (i,k)
```

It's ok that the `j` is bound to `'b'` for the example "abc", you never use it. We can so replace `j` by `_`.

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars =
  item >>= \i ->
  item >>= \_ ->
  item >>= \k ->
  return (i,k)
```

But we also know that `>> :: m a -> m b -> m b` can be defined as:

```
p >> q = p >>= \_ -> q
```

So we are left with

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars =
  item >>= \i ->
  item >>
  item >>= \k ->
  return (i,k)
```

Finally, you can sugar this back into `do`. The application of `>>` simply sugars into a single-line statement with no bounding. It results in:

```
twoChars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twoChars = do
  i <- item
  item
  j <- item
  return (i,j)
```

Hope this cleared some things up.

Comment: great answer! Your explanation of `>>=` did the trick of putting together missing pieces. I suspect most of those new to parsing basics stumble here. Hopefully, when someone writes a `School of Haskell` article derived from functional pearl paper, they can use your answer to expand on it.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `;` is not always syntactic sugar for `>>`.

Rather, we have:

```
do    m ; n  =  m >> n
do x<-m ; n  =  m >>= \x -> n
```

(The above translation is simplified, [the full gory details](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) can be found in the Haskell Report)

So, your definition for `p` is equivalent to:

```
p = item >>= \a -> ( item >> (item >>= \b -> return (a,b) ))
```

Here, you can see that the first and third `item`s do not have their results discarded (because `>>=` binds them to `a` and `b` respectively), while the middle `item` does.

---

Also note that the code

```
\cs -> case cs of
        ""     -> []
       (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)]
```

is misleading since it is defining variable `cs` twice: once in the `\cs` and once in the
pattern `(c:cs)`. It is equivalent to

```
\cs -> case cs of
        ""     -> []
       (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]
```

This clarifies that the final `String` is the output is *not* the original `cs` one, but rather its tail `xs`.

---

In a comment, the poster wondered why the three uses of `item` do not return the same result, i.e., why in `return (a,b)` the character `a` is not equal to `b`. This is due to the `>>=` monadic operator, which in this `Parser` monad automatically feeds the output string `xs` of each `item` occurence to the next one. Indeed, the whole point of this monad is to help feeding the "leftover" output of each parser as the "to-be-consumed" input in the next one. This has two advantages: it frees the programmer from having to write code to pass this string around, and it ensures that the string is not accidentally "rewound" to a previous state. To illustrate the latter point, here's some wrong code:

```
let [(c1,s1)] = someParser someInitialString
    [(c2,s2)] = anotherParser1 s1
    [(c3,s3)] = anotherParser2 s2
    [(c4,s4)] = anotherParser3 s3
    [(c5,s5)] = anotherParser4 s2  -- Whoops! Should have been s4
    in [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
```

In the last step the string, after having been consumed multiple times, is wrongly rolled back to a previous state, as if the parsers `anotherParser2` and `anotherParser3` did not consume anything at all. This error is prevented by composing parsers through `>>=` instead.

Comment: that helps clear up some confusion. I am still unclear how the strings are being dropped before being passed to subsequent `item`. For example, third `item` should still have same identical function in monadic wrapper as first `item`. So, executing it still should give same result as first `item` since the input string doesn't change - so `a` and `b` should be identical. That is clearly not the case.

Comment: You should update your answer to also mention that the `cs` in the `case` statement for `item` is shadowing the `cs` from the lambda, and then you have a complete answer to his question.

Answer (score 1):

The more uniform translation of your

```
p3 = do { a <- item; item; b <- item; return (a,b)}
  -- do { a <- item; z <- item; b <- item; return (a,b)}  -- z is ignored
```

is

```
p3 = item >>= (\a ->
       item >>= (\z ->     
         item >>= (\b ->
           return (a,b))))     -- z is unused
```

(the key observation here is that the functions are *nested*). Which means that

```
-- parse (return a) cs = [(a,cs)]
-- parse (p >>= f)  cs = [r | (a,cs1) <- parse p cs,         -- concat
--                            r       <- parse (f a) cs1] )  --   inlined !
parse p3 cs 
  = [ r | (a,cs1) <- parse item cs,
          r <- [ r | (z,cs2) <- parse item cs1,
                     r <- [ r | (b,cs3) <- parse item cs2,
                                r <-    -- parse (return (a,b)) cs3
                                     [((a,b),cs3)]]]]        -- z is unused

  = [ ((a,b),cs3) | (a,cs1) <- parse item cs,
                    (_,cs2) <- parse item cs1, 
                    (b,cs3) <- parse item cs2]
```

So you see, ["the input string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673237/monadic-parsing-functional-pearl-gluing-multiple-parsers-together?noredirect=1#comment34544703_22673392) does change: first it's `cs`, then `cs1`, then `cs2`.

That is the simple real computation behind all the `Parser` tags and `do` syntax. It's all just about the chaining of inputs and outputs in the nested loops, in the end:

```
parse p3 cs =
    for each (a,cs1) in (parse item cs):
       for each (z,cs2) in (parse item cs1):
          for each (b,cs3) in (parse item cs2):
             yield ((a,b),cs3)
```